# Multi line tab separated file to comma separated

Tags: bash, csv, vim

I have big file which is tab separated. The biggest problem is that I need to import the data into database but some of the columns are multi line which is causing some problems. What I would like to do it to convert the file into proper comma separated file using bash.
Here is the example of the file (I will substitute the tabs with pipe |):

```
1|Some text|another text|12| Some big big big

text with lots of data and multiple lines

and commas|34|34
2|Some text|another text||Another big big big big
text with lots of characters like , and tab|33|25
```

In above example there are basically two lines of data. What I would like to have is:

```
"1","Some text","another text","12"," Some big big big

text with lots of data  and multiple lines

and commas","34","34"
"2","Some text","another text","","Another big big big big
text with lots of characters like , and tab","33","25"
```

In vim I can see that each full line of data (with multiple line column) is terminated by ^M$ so it looks like this:

```
1|Some text|another text|12| Some big big big

text with lots of data and multiple lines

and commas|34|34^M$
2|Some text|another text||Another big big big big
text with lots of characters like , and tab|33|25^M$
```

Comment: If your input file is tab-separated how do you differentiate the tabs which are part of big-big-multiline-text? Are they escaped?

Comment: My bad. I think that this big multi lines column data do not have tabs. I will correct the question.

Comment: I think the tools available with your DB affect what your best solution will be. For example, Oracle tools allow cfg files that would allow line breaks in column data. Consider adding a tag for the DB you will be importing to, as this feature may available for other DBs. Good luck.

Comment: So you do not mind the multiple lines so long as the tab-separated fields are replaced with comma-separated fields, enclosed in quotes?  What do you want to do with commas and quotation marks that are already in the file?

Answer (score 0):

This is really tricky, and it depends on executing the right sequence of substitutions. The following seems to work (at least on your given example):

```
" Enclose non-multiline lines with quotes.
:g/\t/s/^\|\(\r\)$/"\1/g
" Undo the ending quote before / the beginning quote after a multiline.
:v/\t/-1s/"$//
:v/\t/+1s/^"//
" Undo the beginning quote after an incomplete (i.e. no ^M) previous record.
:g/\t/-1s/\r\@<!\n\zs"//
" Replace tabs with quotes and commas.
:%s/\t/","/g
" Finally, remove the ^M end-of-record marker.
:%s/\r$//
```